# Call a function on losing focus from typeahead (Bootstrap UI)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using Bootstrap UI's typeahead. I need to call a different function whenever a new option is selected from the dropdown or user has entered some value. So, for this I tried using `ng-blur`. If we enter 2 or 3 characters and about to make a selection from the dropdown list, `ng-blur` is getting triggered with those 2 or 3 characters and also after making the selection. I want only to trigger the function after losing focus from the typeahead input box.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.selected" placeholder="Select a value..." typeahead="text for text in getOptions($viewValue)" required ng-blur="getDifferentFunction($parent.selected)" typeahead-editable="true" />
```

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a timeout to the on-blur function, that way you get the selected change updates 500ms should do. since the javascript runs parallel it should be doing great.

```
function onBlurAction(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    //your code here
  }, 500);
};
```